# What to do if Apple hosted in-app purchase content download fails?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

Sometimes the download fails and my app finishes the transaction upon failure, as recommended everywhere. But if I finish the transaction then Store Kit fails to resume the failed download. And it also seems Store Kit doesn't automatically retry to download content once download failed, and there also seems to be no way to trigger download.

Has someone figured out what to do in such cases? Go against all recommendation and not finish the transaction until the content has fully been downloaded and installed?

Or must I programmatically restore transactions and ignore all other product identifiers?

Comment: Have you try restoring purchases? I hope it must work.

Comment: Like you say, I do this for now. I don't finish the transaction until download is finished. Also, within the app, I don't mark the product as purchased until the download has finished AND the downloaded file has been copied into documents folder. It would cause a lot of trouble if a product looks like it's purchased, but when you try to access its content its not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button of restore purchase via this way in your app :-

```
//inside of an IBaction
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];


// Then this is called
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
NSLog(@"%@",queue );
NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);  

NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
    NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);
    // here put an if/then statement to write files based on previously purchased items
    // example if ([productID isEqualToString: @"youruniqueproductidentifier]){write files} else { nslog sorry}
  }  
 }
```

**OR**

```
 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Hope this help you...!!

Comment: My app already does all of this. But restoring transactions is intended for the user to take action upon. For example after new install of app with already purchased items. I want to automatically redownload failed downloads until they are complete.

Comment: This guy totally missed that you are using hosted content. I am having the same question as you.